# How to select div element with the same class and do something on clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am here struggling to find a solution for selecting div with similar class in order to remove some class on current (clicked) element.

Here is example of my work. You will se Twitter Bootstrap collapse feature where I am trying to remove class `fa-angle-up` from `panel-title` when user click on another item. This way it will change arrow direction when user click on another item.

http://quadrifoglio-test.esy.es/sample/

ps. I believe I need some vent listener but I don?t know which one and how to use it. Thanks!

here is html structure with jquery which I am using already.

```
     <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
     <!-- Accordition -->
     <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading transition">
           <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
              href="#accordionOne">
              <h4 class="panel-title fa fa-angle-up">
                 <span class="month">oct</span>
                 <span>Hrvatski skup poduzetnika</span>
              </h4>
           </a>
        </div>
        <div id="accordionOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
           <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="main-event">
                 <a href="#">
                    <span>Main event</span> 
                    <img src="img/main_event.jpg">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                       sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
                       aliqua.
                    </p>
                 </a>
              </div>
              <div class="events">
                 <span>Eventi</span>
                 <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Skup amerikanaca podrijetlom iz Hrvatske s rodacima </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Branko ima nesto reci, policija zaustavlja vozace. Sta reci.</a></li>
                 </ul>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>

    <!-- jquery  -->

        $( ".panel-title" ).click(function() {
      $( this ).toggleClass( "fa-angle-up" );
    });

    $( ".panel-title.fa.fa-angle-up" ).click(function() {
      $( this ).toggleClass( "fa-angle-down" );
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page does not work because of the following errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < 403.php:2
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery bootstrap.min.js:11
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

You need to include the necessary scripts (like jQuery).

---

#### Update

You are binding the caret icon to click listeners on the panel which is unreliable. Instead, you want to bind to the bootstrap event like so:

```
function toggleCaret(e) {
    var $target = $(e.currentTarget),
        $div = $($target.find('.collapse')),
        $theLink = $target.find('a[data-toggle="collapse"]').parent(),
        $links = $('a[data-toggle="collapse"]').parent();

    function doUp() {
        $theLink.addClass('fa-angle-up');
        $theLink.removeClass('fa-angle-down');
    }

    function doDown() {
        $links.removeClass('fa-angle-up');
        $links.addClass('fa-angle-down');
    }

    doDown();
    doUp();
}

$('.panel').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    toggleCaret(e);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/DSGxz/308/)

Comment: I believe your code will work but with a little bit adjustments. I have tried to resolve it and adjust it to my code snippet but I wasn't able to do that. Could you please take a look one more time.
http://quadrifoglio-test.esy.es/sample/

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you would wrap your collapsible groups in such a way that the 'shown' and 'hidden' events would affect even the toggle element.

In your case, I guess you could do

```
$('.fa-angle-up').click(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('fa-angle-up');
});

$('.fa-angle-down').click(function() {
  $('.panel-title').removeClass('fa-angle-up');
  $(this).addClass('fa-angle-up');
});
```

However, this will probably not work unless you make the `.panel-title` elements be the ones that manage the collapse behavior. Currently this is done by their parent.

**Edit: It should still be possible to use hidden and shown events.**

```
$(document).on('hidden', '.collapse', function () {
   var panel=$(this).closest('.panel');
   var paneltitle=$('.panel-title',panel);
   paneltitle.removeClass('fa-angle-up');
});

$(document).on('shown', '.collapse', function () {
   var panel=$(this).closest('.panel');
   var paneltitle=$('.panel-title',panel);
   paneltitle.addClass('fa-angle-up');
});
```

Comment: Can you please write html structure according to your explanation?

Comment: never mind, it should still be possible to use hidden and shown events, you just need to go up until you find the parent .panel and then get the handle of the sibling .panel-title element. Please check that out, but remove your current jQuery code on the linked site. There's a snippet causing an error in the end.

Comment: I have tried but unfortunately it doesn't work even when I remove that few lines of distracting jquery code.

Answer (score 0):

well you are not removing the classes at all.. at some point you have both fa-angle-down **and** fa-angle-up on the same element.

according to jQuery docs the only signature that might suit you case is:

```
$( "#foo" ).toggleClass( className, addOrRemove );
```

which is equivalent to:

```
if ( addOrRemove ) {
  $( "#foo" ).addClass( className );
} else {
  $( "#foo" ).removeClass( className );
}
```

i preffer the old-fashion way:

```
$(".panel-title").click(function() 
{
   if ($(this).hasClass("fa-angle-up"))
   {
      $(this).removeClass("fa-angle-up").addClass("fa-angle-down");
   }
   else
   {
       $(this).removeClass("fa-angle-down").addClass("fa-angle-up");
   }
});
```